# Is this link-only answer ok?

Tags: discussion, link-only-answers, specific-answer, disputed-flags

I came across [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8993606/5152001) a while ago and flagged it as not being a 'proper' answer, because it contains no information other than a link to an MSDN page where one of the comments included the resolution to the problem the OP was having.

> [here you can find details about this problem](http://msdn.microsoft.com/query/dev10.query?appId=Dev10IDEF1&l=EN-US&k=k%28EHFILELOAD%29&rd=true)
>
> Hope this will help.

My flag was declined. I think in normal circumstances this kind of answer would not be allowed, is it the case that answers like this should remain if they are accepted and get some up-votes?

Comment: Comments [archived](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/transcript/110323/discussion-on-question-by-glen-thomas-is-this-link-only-answer-ok).

Comment: What type did you flag it as? If you flagged it as NAA, it should have been declined as the answer answers the question.

Comment: @AshishAhujaツ what... answer are you reading? [That's a textbook NAA.](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/225370/213575) It only tells you where to find apples, it isn't giving you one (and even then, it isn't trivial to find the apples either).

Comment: @Braiam Oh that's new to me. I had once flagged a link-only answer as NAA, and my flag was declined. I think even I should have posted in meta. Thanks for letting me know.

Comment: trick with [archiving _uncomfortable_ comments](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/321829/is-this-link-only-answer-ok#comment337561_321829) seems to be getting overused

Comment: Much, much underused @gnat.

Comment: @Shog9 *"but in this case the identity of the moderator who deleted along with the timestamp tells you pretty much all you need to know"* oooooo!  Come on, more hints!

Answer (score 32, accepted):

The flag was declined quite a while ago now, but it appears to have been rejected because the answer *appeared to be useful*. Indeed, some digging reveals that the asker did indeed find his answer buried in the "Community Additions" section of that MSDN article.

Granted, nothing in the answer even hints at the real solution (which the asker perplexingly edited *into his question*) nor even at its location (after the end of the article proper). It's an incredibly fragile, frustratingly cagey way to write an answer... And that's not even getting into the fact that the author of that answer himself is long ago deleted and can do nothing to fix it, nor the reasons for his deletion.

Personally, I would've deleted that answer. In fact, I've now done so purely to allow better answers to rise to the top of the post (and I've also fabricated an answer on behalf of the asker to contain the actual solution referenced by that post).

But there are many opinions on this, and I respect that some moderators may hesitate to take such drastic action. In these cases, you can still do much good by treating such an answer as an invitation to build a *real* answer out of the hints and pointers scattered around the thread; the [answer I fabricated](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8987091/the-invocation-of-the-constructor-on-type-testwpf-mainwindow-that-matches-the/36878631#36878631) could've just as well been edited into the accepted answer with much the same results.

Comment: Wait, what?  You hacked an answer with the OP's account into the post?  Where's the button that lets *me* do that? (inb4 the avalanche of "can you fix this post for me, Shog?" requests)

Comment: No button I'm afraid, @Robert; I kinda had to cheat a bit. If you regularly encounter situations where such a tool would come in handy, let me know. And feel free to make requests for such actions via the "contact CM" tool in the interim; the tool I used exists primarily for fixing up accounts, so anyone handling those should be familiar with it.

Comment: (Scavenger hunt: find the places on MSE where Jeff used this to train new staff in the art of posting answers as answers instead of comments...)

Comment: @Shog9 you did that to me before!

Comment: "some moderators may hesitate to take such drastic action" You're falsely introducing a metric of nonconformity. What matters is not whether an action is drastic or mild but [whether it makes sense](http://waitbutwhy.com/2015/11/the-cook-and-the-chef-musks-secret-sauce.html#4). Not deleting a link only answer that is flagged as a link only answer when it is known and accepted that link only answers are bad and should be deleted doesn't make sense.

Comment: Y'all elect moderators to moderate, @bjb. It should not surprise you when they moderate with moderate moderation.

Comment: @Shog9 Ignoring principles of the site and user consensus isn't moderate moderation.

Comment: So what's your point, @bjb? Drop the fancy language and say what you mean. I took action that clearly makes some people uncomfortable; does that fact bother you?

Comment: @Shog9 I think bjb wants it stated that the moderator was wrong to decline the NAA flag. The answer should have been deleted as NAA, even if your other, "drastic" actions weren't taken.

Comment: Hi @mbrig! In this answer, I've attempted to explain why a moderator took the action that they did, providing along with it my own opinion on the proper course of action and a recommendation for handling situations where a moderator disagrees. A day later, I found myself arguing with some of the top users on another established Stack Exchange site who felt that an answer which pointed the asker to an off-site tutorial for help was more than appropriate & should under no circumstances be deleted. I lost; sysadmins love them some RTFM. Point is, change the things you can, accept what you can't.

Answer (score 27):

<sup>*The issue of the flag handling was well covered in [Shog's answer](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/321833/98786).*</sup>

On the issue of link-only answers — no, it is not okay.

Stack Exchange was built to create a collaborative work of sharing knowledge, so when folks come here searching for answers, **the last thing we should be doing sending them *elsewhere* to find that information.**

A link sending users off to find information on their own is *not* an answer in the context of this site. Being complacent of such activity just adds yet another barrier between the users and the information they seek.

And that does not make the Internet better.

Comment: No mod will disagree with your statement in principle.  The reality is a bit more complicated.  How, for example, do you preserve the integrity of answers without causing information loss? (Convert to comment, for whatever reason, isn't always available, and yes, these arguments have been hashed out on meta many times before)

Comment: @RobertHarvey True, that's why I deferred to shog's answer regarding the specifics. But if agreement regarding link-only answers was truly universal, I would have a lot more free time with my days. You'd be surprised.

Comment: (completing Cartaino's comment) ... and I want more free time.