# SEDE query for # of conversations manually moved to chat seems low

Tags: discussion, comments, data-explorer

When doing some data analysis I ran [a query to find comment conversations that were moved to chat on MSO](https://data.stackexchange.com/meta.stackoverflow/query/647934):

```
SELECT TOP 20000
  *
FROM
  Comments c
WHERE
  c.Text LIKE '%moved to chat%'
ORDER BY
  c.CreationDate DESC
```

Granted this presumably does not include deleted questions, but it only retrieved 32 results (the query shows 43 but 11 of those are false positives from a loose query -- I define false positives, algorithmically, as not containing a chat URL). As a sanity check I [ran it on SO](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/647934) and saw only 923 matches (61 were false positives).

This is... suspiciously low. Does that seem right (mods, does that feel right)? Is my query incorrect?

I'm only looking for conversations manually moved to chat by moderators, not the semi-automatic ones where users take it to chat (i.e. *not* "Let us continue this discussion in chat").

I'm assuming the message always contains the text "moved to chat", and the fact that the results date back to 2011 seems to confirm that that has at least been the case for the past 6 years (before 2011 I don't know why I don't see results; either the move to chat feature was not available or the message was different, as SO has been around since 2008).

Comment: I wonder how often that comment gets deleted?  Even still, 32 seems low

Comment: I couldn't give an accurate estimate because I've personally never used the feature. But given that only moderators can do this, it's reasonable that it hasn't been used a ton. Also, the chat feature itself never existed until like mid-2010-ish, so that 2011 date sounds about right for when a move-to-chat feature would have been implemented.

Comment: With some mod tools, I checked my last 2500 comments. I've written "moved to chat" 249 times. (that is from Dec 25th)

Comment: @BhargavRao On MSO, or on SO (or combined)?

Comment: On SO only, not MSO.

Comment: @animuson It appears the feature (mods moving comments to chat) was implemented only  [in August 2015](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/262154).

Comment: @NormalHuman If I understand  that, the system was there since long, but before that it used to come up only the flag dialog. Now it is present in the mod menu as well.

Comment: @NormalHuman That's when it was added to the mod menu. Before moderators could only access it from the flags page.

Comment: So looking more closely given what NormalHuman just said, the picture is starting to become a bit clearer. I don't see anything of the pattern "Comments are not for extended discussion" before August of *2014*, then a year later I guess it was added to the mod menu. Prior to August 2014 I see a lot of "Discussion \[moved to chat.\]\(link\)", which, due to how common that is, I'm presuming some CM had some script or something that generated that message.

Comment: All that said, since August 5th, 2015 (bluefeet's post), I see 15 moves on MSO, 401 on SO, and 0 (?) on MSE. Still seems low... As for SO most of the remainder occurred between August 5th 2014 and August 5th 2015 (504 during that time, interesting... but not sure what to make of it).

Comment: @JasonC Can you check from Nov 23rd 2016? I can check all of my previous comments (from the mod tools and tell you an accurate figure).

Comment: @BhargavRao Since Nov 23 2016 I see 269 total on SO (245 are yours) and 6 total on MSO (0 are yours), noting that these are only comments visible on SEDE (so, not deleted comments, and presumably not on deleted posts).

Comment: I count 305 as mine, (but that is including this week). SEDE is one week stale, so yeah, I think it is correct.

Comment: Now I somehow have to summarize this all in an answer. So many numbers... maybe just... one more episode of Family Guy before I do. Just one.

Comment: Yeah, I'm waiting for your answer as well. I'm dead surprised, BTW. I guess, if SE's chat server explodes, I'll have to take the blame. (Need to reduce moving comments :/)

Comment: @BhargavRao Preserving content for the win!

Comment: Sssh, @Jeremy, don't say that loudly, else Shog will hear you and "archive" the comments :p

Comment: @BhargavRao Haha, we were [just talking about that](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/273553/is-it-common-or-desirable-for-moderators-of-one-se-site-to-actively-influence-mo#comment889787_273553).

Comment: Lol, yep. He's does that a lot. But apparently it is ["Much, much underused"](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/321829/is-this-link-only-answer-ok#comment337611_321829). I've archived the comments once or twice, when the comment thread had some value, but was no longer needed to be there on the site.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

So here's what I've learned from the comments here, conversations in chat, and further investigation.

First, yes, the query is roughly correct. It's in the right ballpark, even though there are a few things lowering my numbers:

- Deleted comments (not possible to retrieve).
- Comments on deleted posts (not possible to retrieve).
- Custom move messages that don't match my pattern ([for example](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/273553/is-it-common-or-desirable-for-moderators-of-one-se-site-to-actively-influence-mo#comment889787_273553), might be possible to retrieve, or get close, with some guesses and processing outside of SEDE).

Also, there are a few key dates:

- [2010-ish](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/345972/sede-query-for-of-conversations-manually-moved-to-chat-seems-low#comment459538_345972): Chat was born.
- [2011-ish](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/345972/sede-query-for-of-conversations-manually-moved-to-chat-seems-low#comment459538_345972): Ability to move comments to chat was likely implemented around this time. Prior to this time period I observe no chat links in comments with text containing "moved".
- [August 2014](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/345972/sede-query-for-of-conversations-manually-moved-to-chat-seems-low#comment459553_345972): Presumably when "move to chat" became a tool available to CMs. Prior to this I observe no messages of the form "Conversation is not for extended discussion...". There *are* a number of messages of the form *"Discussion moved to chat."* before this date, my only guess is that some CM had some custom tool to help them move comments.
- [August 2015](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/345972/sede-query-for-of-conversations-manually-moved-to-chat-seems-low#comment459551_345972) ([see also](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/262154)): When "move to chat" became an option in the moderator control panel, available to moderators and not just CMs.

For the curious, the numbers I see in those date ranges (SEDE query as given, minus comments that do not contain chat URLs, SEDE last updated March 19, 2017):

```
                    SO   MSO   MSE
Before 7/31/11       0     0     0
7/31/11 to 8/1/14   17     0     2 
8/1/14 to 8/5/15   505    17     4
8/5/15 to 3/19/17  401    15     0
Total              923    32     6
```

Corroborating that data:

- For SO/MSO/MSE, [Jeremy Banks reports](https://chat.meta.stackexchange.com/rooms/89/conversation/chat-move-1) 532/33/11 since August 2015 compared to my 401/15/0. The orders of magnitude are correct, and deleted comments and posts make sense for the remainder:

  - [18.5% of posts on SO are deleted](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/647995).
  - Removing 18.5% of Jeremy's 532 leaves ~434, close enough to my 401 that I'm satisfied that this passes this sanity check.
- For SO, [Bhargav Rao](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/345972/sede-query-for-of-conversations-manually-moved-to-chat-seems-low#comment459560_345972) reports 305 chat moves done by him since Nov 23, 2016. [I see 269](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/345972/sede-query-for-of-conversations-manually-moved-to-chat-seems-low/345978#comment459559_345972) done by him since that time. This also seems reasonable:

  - Mine should be a bit less regardless as SEDE's data is 5 days old at this point.
  - Removing 18.5% of Bhargav's 305 leaves ~249, also close enough to convince me.

So, yeah, while my queries will always be ~20% short (at least on SO), they're roughly accurate and in the ballpark of the true numbers. Nothing seems blatantly out of place. The only thing I can really do to improve is to work on ways to capture some of the customized move messages that don't match my text pattern.

Thanks for digging into it, all!

---

### Improved (Maybe) Query:

After much testing and confirmation I was able to come up with what appears to be a more accurate query:

```
SELECT
  *
FROM
  Comments
WHERE
  Text LIKE '%/discussion-on-%' AND Text LIKE '%://chat.%'
```

Additionally , `%/discussion-between-%` can be used to find cases where *users* moved their comments to chat, for example:

```
SELECT
  COUNT(CASE WHEN Text LIKE '%/discussion-on-%' THEN 1 ELSE NULL END) ModMoved,
  COUNT(CASE WHEN Text LIKE '%/discussion-between-%' THEN 1 ELSE NULL END) UserMoved,
  COUNT(*) Total
FROM
  Comments
WHERE
  Text LIKE '%://chat.%'
```

Some notes:

- For the most part `%/discussion-on-%` and `%/discussion-between-%` are the primary indicators, but I've chosen to include `%://chat.%` for two reasons:

  - It keeps the second query above from timing out.
  - It filters out links to posts whose title starts with "discussion on". On SO there is [exactly one comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18136441/deselect-selected-item-in-wpf-tree-view-mvvm/38593019#comment64617559_38593019) that falls into this category, so the effect is negligible there, but I did not examine metas or other sites and so decided not to take any chances.
- I confirmed the accuracy of these queries to my satisfaction using the following method:

  1. I pulled 90,854 comments from SO, MSO, MSE, Worldbuilding, and English matching '%://chat.%'.
  2. I visited the links parsed from 6,450 randomly selected comments from that set (that's all I had time for given throttling) and attempted to parse out the room description and transcript.
  3. If a description was present and started with "imported from a comment discussion", I considered that to be a true comment move.
  4. I then checked the correlation between the results of this scan and the presence of "/discussion-on-" and "/discussion-between-".

  Some notes on this:

  - I found that it was not necessary to verify that the first post in the room was from the *Feed* user.
  - I did not verify that the link appeared to be a room associated with the post the comment was found on. I am confident that this did not significantly affect the results, but it could be worth looking into (for example, if the room name contains the name of the author of the post, or if the *Feed* post equals the post the comment was found under). Links that did not match their post would represent users commenting with links to other comment chat rooms. This appears rare but could account for some of the new items detected by this query that were not present before.

  The results:

  - Correct results: 6,438 of 6,450
  - False "positives": 9 (debatable, most of these were users creating rooms but not using the automatic feature).
  - False "negatives": 3 (these were all users posting links to chat rooms manually, without the room title in the URL, they are arguably true negatives).

  So I am satisfied with this. The numbers may be *slightly* (e.g. a fraction of a percent) inflated by users posting links to other posts' chat rooms but the fact that I can't see deleted posts dwarfs this.

The new numbers with this query, for mod-moved comments ("/discussion-on-") are:

```
                    SO   MSO   MSE
Before 7/31/11       0     0     0
7/31/11 to 8/1/14    6     0     0 
8/1/14 to 8/5/15   511    20     5
8/5/15 to 3/26/17  448    37     9
Total              965    57    14
```

These are also a bit closer to the -18.5% projections from Jeremy's SO numbers. Bhargav's numbers increased to 283 (out of 314 total) on SO since Nov 23 2016.

For user-moved comments, for the curious:

```
                      SO   MSO   MSE
Before 7/31/11       659     0     1
7/31/11 to 8/1/14  31609     0    53 
8/1/14 to 8/5/15   15826    18    22
8/5/15 to 3/26/17  32963    53    24
Total              81057    71   100
```

[Here is a query I've made that summarizes a whole bunch of stuff.](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/648368/comment-move-stats?DateCutoff=2015-08-05+00%3A00%3A00)

---

*Note: I just now realized SEDE was updated earlier today, so my "Improved Query" set of numbers had an extra week's worth of posts in it compared to the original, which could explain some of the increase in numbers, too. I don't really feel like it's worth the effort to bring everything into sync here so I've just corrected the date ranges in the tables above.*

Comment: @Bhargav Oh no! So sorry about that.